# how to use where clause when document data contains map value in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]I am learning firebase and trying to create a chat app...

I tap on the user list to check whether him chatroom is already created with l

- List item

logged user or not....and for that, I have created a future function...but showing an error..looks like it denies to use [ breaker with where clause....if it is so, then how to get the value of the map's key...generally I use, varmap['key'].

```
Future<ChatroomModel?> getchatroom(UserModel targetuser) async {
    ChatroomModel? temp;
    QuerySnapshot querysnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('chatrooms')
        .where("participants[${widget.usermodel.userid}]", isEqualTo: true)
        .where("participants[${targetuser.userid}]", isEqualTo: true)
        .get();

    if (querysnapshot.docs.length > 0) {
     
      print("already exists");
    } else {
     

      print("Created new one");
    }

    return temp;
  }
```

this is my chatroommodel

```
class ChatroomModel
{
  String? chatroomid;
  Map<String,dynamic>? participants;//{'xdsfsdf':true, 'afdafd':true}
  String? lastmessage;

  ChatroomModel({this.chatroomid, this.participants,this.lastmessage});

  ChatroomModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    chatroomid=map['chatroomid'];
    participants=map['participants'];
    lastmessage=map['lastmessage'];
  }

  Map<String,dynamic> toMap()
  {
    return {
      'chatroomid':chatroomid,
      'participants':participants,
      'lastmessage':lastmessage,
    };
  }


}
```

getting following error

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/field_path.dart': Failed assertion: line 50 pos 16: '!path.contains('[')': Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'.
```

Comment: can you include your Firestore field?

Comment: I have added an image of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
QuerySnapshot querysnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('chatrooms')
        .where("participants." + widget.usermodel.userid, isEqualTo: true)
        .where("participants." + targetuser.userid, isEqualTo: true)
        .get();
```

Comment: I have taken key's value to bool for blocking system...like if someone has blocked ,,than it will be converted to false,,,, so if I paste your coding, it will be hard for me to manage as learning.... its not allowing [ means it has other options

Comment: specially, I have taken where clause to compare with bool value.....

Comment: ok, get it. please check the updated answer.

Comment: Yes...done....but why to use dot instead of [     normally we access map's key value with [ ], can u explain sir.pls...

Comment: in dart yes we access to map's value by call `['key']` , but in firebase we need to use `.` to access too map's value.

Comment: Ohhh got it.....here I have to follow firebase syntaxes....ufffff.....learning is like endless...Well, Thanks a lot